# Select on multiple tables with group by

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, aggregate, window-functions

Using Postgres 9.3, I have problem with a select over few tables. 
I have simcards stock and I would like to get something like this:

```
| network | supplier | total topups (EUR) | 1st topup qty|   
| three   | three    | 500                | 34           |  
| three   | core     | 300                | 4            |  
| o2      | o2       | 100                | 3            |  

| network | supplier | total topups (EUR) | 2nd topup qty|   
| three   | three    | 200                | 4            |  

| network | supplier | total topups (EUR) | 3rd topup qty|   
| three   | three    | 200                | 4            |
```

my table schemas are:

- simcard(id, iccid(unique), network_id, supplier_id)
- topup(id, date, amount, simcard_id)
- network(id, name)
- supplier(id, name)

at the moment I am able to select all first topups, but I don't know how to display them in a format as I would like (`network| supplied by| topups sum| 1st topup qty`)
Then I have no idea how to select 2nd, 3rd topup for every simcard. I tried with `limit 1 offset 1` or `offset 2` but it didn't work.

```
select 
    distinct topup.iccid    
    , s.created_date
    , n.name as "network"
    , p.name as "supplier"
from
(
select 
    s.iccid as "iccid"
    , t.date

from 
    simcard_topup as t
    join simcard_simcard as s
        on t.iccid_id = s.id
--where 
--  CAST(t.date AS DATE) = date '2015-03-13' - integer '14'

group by
    s.iccid
    , t.date
order by
    t.date asc
) as topup
join simcard_simcard as s
    on topup.iccid = s.iccid
join simcard_network as n
    on s.network_id = n.id
join simcard_supplier as p
    on s.supplier_id = p.id
```

Comment: Please always provide your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT st.topup_nr, n.name AS network, p.name AS supplier
     , st.topup_sum, st.topup_qty
FROM  (
   SELECT t.topup_nr, s.network_id, s.supplier_id
        , sum(t.amount) AS topup_sum
        , count(*) AS topup_qty
   FROM  (
      SELECT simcard_id, amount
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY simcard_id, ORDER BY date) AS topup_nr
      FROM   simcard_topup
      ) t
   JOIN   simcard_simcard s ON s.id = t.simcard_id  -- or so I assume
   GROUP  BY 1,2,3
   ) st
JOIN   simcard_network  n ON n.id = st.network_id
JOIN   simcard_supplier p ON p.id = st.supplier_id
ORDER  BY st.topup_nr, st.topup_qty DESC NULLS LAST
                     , st.topup_sum DESC NULLS LAST;
```

#### Notes

- The core feature is the [window function `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in the inner subquery to number topups per simcard. This makes aggregating for 1st, 2nd etc. topup  in the outer query simple.
- For lack of information, assuming to join `simcard_simcard` to `simcard_topup` on `s.id = t.simcard_id`, though you also have `on t.iccid_id = s.id` in your code, which seems backwards ...
- Don't use a basic type name like `date` as column name.
- Why do you have `CAST(t.date AS DATE)` in your code? A date should be a `date`, so no need to cast it to `date`. Also, it seems we only need the date for ranking topups.
- Counting per `(network_id, supplier_id)` and sorting the result by `... topup_qty DESC, topup_sum DESC`, so the combination with the most topups comes first. [`NULLS LAST` is just to be safe against NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492).

Comment: wow... now I need to study it a lot to make sure I understand what it does. thank you very much specially for tips how to improve my coding.